# 64 bit Word code crashing Word on SetPrinter

Tags: vba, winapi, ms-word, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have inherited some VBA code that needs to be updated to work in 64 bit Office. I am under the impression that changing Long to Longptr and adding PTRSafe to the declaration of functions is the majority of the work. The problem that I am having is that when I call the SetPrinterA function, Word crashes and I am unable to work out why. See code below:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "SetPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As LongPtr, ByVal Level As LongPtr, pPrinter As Byte, ByVal Command As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Function SetPrinterProperty(ByVal psPrinterName As String, ByVal iPropertyType As LongPtr, ByVal iPropertyValue As LongPtr) As Boolean

'Code adapted from Microsoft KB article Q230743

Dim hPrinter As LongPtr        'handle for the current printer
Dim pd As PRINTER_DEFAULTS
Dim pinfo As PRINTER_INFO_2
Dim dm As DEVMODE
Dim yDevModeData() As Byte         'Byte array to hold contents
                                  'of DEVMODE structure
Dim yPInfoMemory() As Byte        'Byte array to hold contents
                                  'of PRINTER_INFO_2 structure                                      
Dim iBytesNeeded As LongPtr
Dim iRet As LongPtr
Dim iJunk As LongPtr
Dim iCount As LongPtr

'On Error GoTo cleanup

pd.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ACCESS_USE
'pd.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS
'pd.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_NORMAL_ACCESS

iRet = OpenPrinter(psPrinterName, hPrinter, pd)
If (iRet = 0) Or (hPrinter = 0) Then
   'Can't access current printer. Bail out doing nothing
   Exit Function
End If

'Get the size of the DEVMODE structure to be loaded
iRet = DocumentProperties(0, hPrinter, psPrinterName, 0, 0, 0)    

If (iRet < 0) Then
   'Can't access printer properties.
   GoTo cleanup
End If

'Make sure the byte array is large enough
'Some printer drivers lie about the size of the DEVMODE structure they
'return, so an extra 100 bytes is provided just in case!

'here
ReDim yDevModeData(0 To CLng(iRet) * 24) As Byte

'Load the byte array
iRet = DocumentProperties(0, hPrinter, psPrinterName, CLngPtr(yDevModeData(0)), 0, DM_OUT_BUFFER)

If (iRet < 0) Then
   GoTo cleanup
End If

'Copy the byte array into a structure so it can be manipulated
Call CopyMemory(dm, yDevModeData(0), Len(dm))

If dm.dmFields And iPropertyType = 0 Then
   'Wanted property not available. Bail out.
   GoTo cleanup
End If

'Set the property to the appropriate value
Select Case iPropertyType
Case DM_ORIENTATION
   dm.dmOrientation = CInt(iPropertyValue)
Case DM_PAPERSIZE
   dm.dmPaperSize = CInt(iPropertyValue)
Case DM_PAPERLENGTH
   dm.dmPaperLength = CInt(iPropertyValue)
Case DM_PAPERWIDTH
   dm.dmPaperWidth = CInt(iPropertyValue)
Case DM_DEFAULTSOURCE
   dm.dmDefaultSource = CInt(iPropertyValue)
Case DM_PRINTQUALITY
   dm.dmPrintQuality = CInt(iPropertyValue)
Case DM_COLOR
   dm.dmColor = CInt(iPropertyValue)
Case DM_DUPLEX
   dm.dmDuplex = CInt(iPropertyValue)
End Select

'Load the structure back into the byte array
Call CopyMemory(yDevModeData(0), dm, Len(dm))

'Tell the printer about the new property
iRet = DocumentProperties(0, hPrinter, psPrinterName, yDevModeData(0), yDevModeData(0), DM_IN_BUFFER Or DM_OUT_BUFFER)

If (iRet < 0) Then
   GoTo cleanup
End If

'The code above *ought* to be sufficient to set the property
'correctly. Unfortunately some brands of Postscript printer don't
'seem to respond correctly. The following code is used to make
'sure they also respond correctly.
Call GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, 0, 0, iBytesNeeded)
If (iBytesNeeded = 0) Then
   'Couldn't access shared printer settings
   GoTo cleanup
End If



'Set byte array large enough for PRINTER_INFO_2 structure
ReDim yPInfoMemory(0 To CLng(iBytesNeeded) + 100) As Byte

'Load the PRINTER_INFO_2 structure into byte array
iRet = GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, yPInfoMemory(0), iBytesNeeded, iJunk)
If (iRet = 0) Then
   'Couldn't access shared printer settings
   GoTo cleanup
End If

'Copy byte array into the structured type
Call CopyMemory(pinfo, yPInfoMemory(0), Len(pinfo))

'Load the DEVMODE structure with byte array containing
'the new property value
pinfo.pDevmode = yDevModeData(0)

'Set security descriptor to null
pinfo.pSecurityDescriptor = 0

'Copy the PRINTER_INFO_2 structure back into byte array
Call CopyMemory(yPInfoMemory(0), pinfo, Len(pinfo))
'Send the new details to the printer

MsgBox hPrinter
MsgBox yPInfoMemory(0)    

iRet = SetPrinter(ByVal hPrinter, 2, yPInfoMemory(0), 0)

'Indicate whether it all worked or not!
SetPrinterProperty = CBool(iRet)
```

As you can see below when running API Monitor I am getting no return value for SetPrinter and Word Crashes. Please let me know if you need any more information.

[image: SetPrinter has no return value]

Comment: Could you add your API function declaration?

Comment: @VincentG done, my apologies.

Comment: AFAIK, declaration should be `Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "SetPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As LongPtr, ByVal Level As Long, pPrinter As Byte, ByVal Command As Long) As Long`. Level and Command are not pointer, neither is the return value. You have to check the parameters, do not change all `Long` to `LongPtr`.

Comment: I'm also quite sure all `i...` variable are expected to be `Long`, not `LongPtr`

Comment: @VincentG I have just replaced the declaration with yours and I have also changed the i... variables back to longs but still no luck, Word is crashing still. Is there any way of getting a better error than using API Monitor? Thanks

Comment: API calls are very tricky. Have you adapted the code for the other API calls in your code? I see some `CopyMemory` calls, some `GetPrinter` calls... but without the full declaration code it's difficult to say.

Comment: `DocumentProperties` also might be faulty. List all API calls, all variables used by those calls, and check all declaration of those API functions and variables.

Comment: There are tools that can help you, like the [Windows API Viewer](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm)

Comment: *"Is there any way of getting a better error than using API Monitor?"* - Yes. Attach a debugger to Word, and set it up to break, when an exception is raised. That'll get you loads of valuable insights, including the exact location, where the error is raised. Knowing how to read disassembly is required, though.